# handling an uploaded file via FileStream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filestream

I am allowing the user to upload a file(doc, pdf, excel, txt) and then i am passing in FileStream to read and then write but after opening it i am calling a stored procedure so i can store the file name, date, upload user and where i will be a copy of it. My problem is how can deal with the string filename that has been pased in the FileStream and the stored procedure wants a string filename.

```
string docx = @"../../TestFiles/Test.docx";
try
 {
     FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(docx, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     docConverter.UpLoadFile(11, "Test.docx", "../../TestFiles/", 1, "../../Temp/", 89);
 }

public void UpLoadFile(int studentId, string rawStoragePath, int uploadedByUserId,   string storagePath, int assignmentElementsId)
 {
     Guid strGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
     DateTime uploadDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

     //calling stored procedure                
     stuSubSvc.UploadWork(studentId, strGUID, (need to pass file name), rawStoragePath,  uploadDate, uploadedByUserId, storagePath, 0, assignmentElementsId);
 }
```

Help with:
1 - getting file name from file in FileStream
2 - getting path of the uploaded file from FileStream

Comment: What about using rawStoragePath cause in your sample it's itself a filename.

Comment: @vendettamit i figured that i could use fileStream.Name to get the full path of the file being uploaded but is there a way that i could get 'Test.docx' instead of '../../Test.docx'?

Comment: try Path.GetFileName(".././Test.docx")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 - getting file name from file in FileStream

There's no filename in a stream. You can get the filename of the uploaded file from the `HttpPostedFileBase` instance that your controller action receives as parameter. Take a look at Phil Haack's [`blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) about uploading files in an ASP.NET MVC application in which he illustrates that.

Assuming you have already stored the file on your file system, you could retrieve the filename from the Name property of the FileStream:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileStream.Name);
```

> 2 - getting path of the uploaded file from FileStream

There's no filename nor filepath in a stream. All you can hope of getting is the filename which is contained in the `HttpPostedFileBase` instance that your controller action should receive as parameter (see previous point).

Answer (score 1):

you can't get the path of the file on the client machine. The FileStrame has a property called Handle that contains the native handle of the opened file, you follow the following article it will help you to get the file name by the handle, it is in C++ but the all functions are APIs can be called using P/Invoke in C# [DllImport].

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789(v=vs.85).aspx

**Edit**

---

Sorry the Handle is obsolete use ***SafeFileHandle*** instead

Answer (score 1):

To get the filename out of full path you can use:

```
Path.GetFileName(".././Test.docx")
```

It'll give you `Test.docx`